# Connecting android app to xampp

Tags: android, mysql

Is it possible to connect our android App to xampp? If so, how do we connect it?. My fellow friend told me it is possible by downloading xampp and noc. I have never tried this before though, I am curious about the other way to connect our android App to mysql beside using sqlite.

Any answer I will appreciate ! Thx.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it possible to connect our android App to xampp?

Yes, you need third party, which is `php`.

You may refer to
[How to connect Android with PHP, MySQL](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/05/how-to-connect-android-with-php-mysql/).

Comment: It's worth to give a try. Thanks!! Very helpful resource indeed.